# finding the limit algebraically

Tags: calculus, limits

Struggling to find
$$
\lim_{x\to-2}\left(\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{4}{x^2-4}\right)
$$

I know the answer is $-1/4$, but I still can't get to it algebraically, without a calculator

Comment: how did you do it with a calculator?

Comment: Note that it's ***impossible*** to decide limits with calculators. They can only give hints.

Comment: I used the limit calculator at mathportal.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Big Hint**

$$\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{4}{x^2-4}=\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{4}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\frac{1}{x+2}\left(1+\frac{4}{x-2}\right)=\frac{1}{x+2}\left(\frac{x+2}{x-2}\right)=\frac{1}{x-2}$$

Comment: It's not a hint, it's a full solution